# Add filters to a route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Here's my route:

```
Route::controller('/site-manager-gateway', 'SiteManagerGatewayController');
```

How can I apply a CSRF filter and Auth filter, I've tried adding them like:

```
Route::controller('/site-manager-gateway', 'SiteManagerGatewayController', array('before' => 'auth' | 'csrf'));
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap multiple controllers/actions in a group, and apply filter for whole group. I think this is best practice, as you don't have to repeat yourself on each route.

Also, you have to specify filters in string

```
'filterA|filterB'
```

not

```
'filterA' | 'filterB'
```

So the router looks like:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|csrf'), function()
{
    Route::controller('/site-manager-gateway', 'SiteManagerGatewayController');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters and check out "Attaching multiple routes to a filter"

```
Route::get('user', array('before' => 'auth|old', function()
{
    return 'You are authenticated and over 200 years old!';
}));
```

By looking at your code you separated the auth and csrf with single quotes when they should be placed together so instead of 'auth' | 'csrf' you need 'auth | csrf'.